# Python function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python

I am trying to parse gmail emails. From http://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/python-imaplib-imap-example-with-gmail/ I have the following:

```
def get_first_text_block(self, email_message_instance):
    maintype = email_message_instance.get_content_maintype()
    if maintype == 'multipart':
        for part in email_message_instance.get_payload():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
                return part.get_payload()
    elif maintype == 'text':
        return email_message_instance.get_payload()    

def hello(request):
    ....   

    first = qs[0]
    one = first.get_email_object()
    print one['To']    

    out = get_first_text_block(one)
```

I'm getting:

```
get_first_text_block() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove the `self` argument in `def get_first_text_block`, unless it is a class method

Comment: Quick! Remove this question before Ignacio sees it and tears you a new one about not having read your own code! **Oh wait...**

Comment: Are these functions inside a class?

Comment: These functions are inside a django view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to invoke the function through a View instance.

**It's a common error in Django users don't instantiate class Views when writting url patterns. If you have the view "MyView" you must provide an instance MyView() to the url pattern.**

If you have some class:

```
class SomeClass:
    def some_function(self, foo): pass
```

you must call it like this:

```
some_instance = SomeClass()
some_instance.some_function(foo)
```

if you call it like this:

SomeClass.some_function(foo)

you don't have actually passed a object (self) as first param to some_function.

Answer (score 5):

`self` is usually used for instance methods, passing a pointer of the instance to the function.

Well, we don't seem to need it here. You can just omit it:

```
def get_first_text_block(email_message_instance):
    maintype = email_message_instance.get_content_maintype()
    if maintype == 'multipart':
        for part in email_message_instance.get_payload():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
                return part.get_payload()
    elif maintype == 'text':
        return email_message_instance.get_payload()
```

I don't know where you get this code from, but i hope this works as expected!

Answer (score 3):

The `self` argument is only used when you define a function as a class method.
So if you want your function to be a global function in your module you should remove it.
Besides in your code I don see why you need a the argument `self`?

Answer (score 2):

You've defined get_first_text_block as if it was a instance method by having 'self' as the first parameter. But it's actually just a function. Make the function definition look like this:

```
def get_first_text_block(email_message_instance):
```

And it will work.

Comment: Actually `self` usually denotes an instance method. "class methods" take the class (usually noted `cls`) as first argument.

Comment: Oops, that's actually a typo. I caught the mistake earlier and added "instance" in there, but forgot to delete "class", which left the weird looking "class instance method". I'll fix it, thanks.